# How to clear values except for N/A in Google sheet script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created this app script, which looks for the text "Check" in column I and will clear contents in Columns J, K and L. I would like to modify the script to clear contents except for when cell has N/A as a value.

Here is the Google App Script that I created.

```
function ClearCells() {
  const sheetName = "Example"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const searchText = "Check";
  const ranges = sheet
    .getRange("I3:I" + sheet.getLastRow())
    .createTextFinder(searchText)
    .matchCase(true)
    .findAll()
    .flatMap(r => {
      const row = r.getRow();
      return ["J","K","L"].map(e => e + row);
    }); 
  if (ranges.length > 0) sheet.getRangeList(ranges).clearContent();
}
```

Comment: I'm aassuming you mean `#N/A` which is the result of a formula.   So you want to keep the formula in any cell that has `#N/A`?

Comment: @TheWizEd That is correct. I want to keep the `N/A` value. I've tried your modified script but got the following result where the `N/A` values were not being kept for the  rows with "Check". Please see the following screenshot [link](https://www.screencast.com/t/tzxII5pg). Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is the `N/A` the result of a formula or is it just text?

Comment: @TheWizEd `N/A` is just a text, not a result of a formula.

Comment: @TheWizEd Thanks for the updated solution. I was wondering if there is a way to modify the row.offset to include additional columns in the future. In addition to columns J, K and L, I want to include another set of columns (N, O, and P). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at [Range.offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is waht you are looking for, but it will clear the contents of any row which "Check" in column I and leave the formula that results in `#N/A`.

I create a mock up of your sheet using the function `=NA()` to produce the value `#N/A`.

[image]

In Code.gs (if `#N/A` is due to formula)

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let check = sheet.getRange(3,9,sheet.getLastRow()-2,1);
    let textFinder = check.createTextFinder("Check");
    let checked = textFinder.findAll();
    let ranges = checked.map( row => {
        return row.offset(0,1,1,3);  // columns J,K,L
      }
    );
    ranges.forEach( range => {  // each range is a single row
        let values = range.getValues()[0];
        let formulas = range.getFormulas()[0];
        values = values.map( (value,index) => {
            return value === "#N/A" ? formulas[index] : "";
          }
        );
        range.setValues([values]);
      }
    );
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

In Code.gs (if `#N/A` is simply text)

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let check = sheet.getRange(3,9,sheet.getLastRow()-2,1);
    let textFinder = check.createTextFinder("Check");
    let checked = textFinder.findAll();
    let ranges = checked.map( row => {
        return row.offset(0,1,1,3);  // columns J,K,L
      }
    );
    ranges.forEach( range => {  // each range is a single row
        let values = range.getValues()[0];
        values = values.map( (value,index) => {
            return value === "#N/A" ? value : "";
          }
        );
        range.setValues([values]);
      }
    );
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

And the results are

[image]

Comment: I have provided a solution for both result of a formula or simply just text.